# UWP - How to use Resources.resw in class library

Tags: c#, resources, uwp, dynamic-library

in library

```
        public string GetName()
    {
        ResourceLoader rl = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("ClassLibrary1/Resources");

        return rl.GetString("Name");
    }
```

at "ResourceLoader rl = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("ClassLibrary1/Resources");"

An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in ClassLibrary1.dll but was not handled in user code

WinRT information: 未找到 ResourceMap。

Additional information: 未找到 ResourceMap。

未找到 ResourceMap。

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

**if i add reference this library , it is working well.
but i Dynamic reference this library ,it is failure.**

```
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("ClassLibrary1"));
        if (assembly == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        Type type = assembly.GetType("ClassLibrary1.Class1");
        ICore core = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as ICore;
        textBlock1.Text = core.GetName();

        //ClassLibrary1.Class1 c1 = new ClassLibrary1.Class1();
        //textBlock1.Text = c1.GetName(); //it is working well
```

**how to use resources for Dynamic reference in the library?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if i add reference this library , it is working well. but i Dynamic reference this library ,it is failure.

Most of your code is right, you didn't mention what exactly the exception is. Here is my demo:

Portable class library, class1:

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ClassLib Loaded!");
    }

    public void Output()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ClassLib method!");
    }
}
```

In UWP app:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("ClassLibrary1"));
if (assembly == null)
{
    return;
}
Type type = assembly.GetType("ClassLibrary1.Class1");
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
var method = type.GetMethod("Output");
method.Invoke(obj, null);
```

The output in the immediate window is like this:

[image]

To do this, you will **need to**:

1. build your class library.
2. right click your class lib, choose "Open folder in File Explorer", in the folder find the "bin" folder => "Debug", copy the `ClassLibrary1.dll` into your UWP project like this:

[image]

Although doing this can solve the problem, but in my personal opinion, it seems not easier than directly adding reference of this library.

Comment: thank you for Answer，i want to use the Dynamic reference type to load ".dll", and use ".dll"  own resources, because the app will add ".dll" Dynamic when i needed

Comment: @wangji, you mean you want to find the .dll file and load it in run time? You can have a try, I'm not sure your file location is accessible in UWP app since UWP apps run in sandbox...If your app won't be published to the store, there is method to use Win32 api in UWP app...

Comment: @wangji, after a little researching, there is no method to load .dll file which is not copied into the installed folder using traditionally UWP api, you will need to either reference the lib or manually copy into the app. Alternatively you can break the container of UWP app to use Win32 API.

Comment: thank you for your help.I am programing for Win10 iot.I can load “dll” in run time and won't be published to the store. but it can not use win32 API,so i find the problem.